# Where is bitcoin-qt's blockchain stored in Windows 7?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I need to manually resync from scratch due to a database corruption caused by windows auto-rebooting.

Where is the blockchain stored so I can delete it (and hopefuly prompt bitcoin qt from creating a new one)?

see [Bitcoin QT error. How can I prevent corruption of database?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/bitcoin-qt-error-how-can-i-prevent-corruption-of-database)

Answer (score 2):

Start your client with the `-reindex` command-line option. This will cause the database to be wiped and rebuilt from scratch.

To answer your actual question: see the [Data directory](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory) entry on the Bitcoin wiki.